# Invalid content was found starting with element 'authentication-manager'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I get error with spring configuration:

```
Invalid content was found starting with element 'authentication-manager'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"]}' is expected.
```

Here is the bean xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.rsc."/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
            <password-encoder ref="encoder"></password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl" class="com.rsc.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></bean>

    <bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <constructor-arg name="strength" value="11"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I have added all the required bean configuration but still I am getting error. What I am i missing in the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add the spring security namespace.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"         
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

   [...]

   <security:authentication-manager>
      ...
   </security:authentication-manager>  

   [...]

</beans>
```

since `beans` is your default namespace spring tries to find the `authentication-manager` there. Therefore you need to introduce the `security` namespace. See the documentation for further information: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e507